# Deleting the entered names in the "TO" field using NSTokenField

Tags: nstokenfield

I am working with NSTokenField, the requirement is similar to apple mail application. 
I have delegate methods to format the strings and add to the field.
Do I get any delegate method for deletion of the tokens, as of now I am not able to get the control for deletion of the text.
Could any one please help?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post - [Callback for deleting NSTokenFieldCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357624/callback-for-deleting-nstokenfieldcell)

And this - [no tokenField:willDeleteObjects:](http://openradar.appspot.com/9000191)

Hope this helps !