# How to create UI tags in Cocoa Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, tags

I'm looking into building a tagging feature in my Mac app. I would like to do something like in the attached image. Is the UI portion offered natively in Cocoa? If so, what is the class name?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSTokenField to accomplish that. Start by reading [Token Field Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do exactly that a couple of weeks ago. I decided to use NSTokenField as well but ran into quite a number of problems. See my endeavours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618345/nstokenfield-and-deleting-tokens/8626374#8626374). Hope you fare better with your implementation as it gave me a couple of really short nights....